# Writing one hot encoding to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am currently trying to write one hot encoding to csv, using df.to_csv but when I write it takes the original state the data was in instead of the one hot. I tried renaming the df but a tuple error came up. The code is below.

```
Code:

df = pd.read_csv('Filename.txt')
df.columns = ['Date','b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6']
df = df.set_index('Date')

reversed_df = df.iloc[::-1]

n=5
print('Game')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
print(reversed_df.drop(df.index[n:-n]),("\n"))

BallOne = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b1)
BallTwo = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b2)
BallThree = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b3)
BallFour = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b4)
BallFive = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b5)
BallSix = pd.get_dummies(reversed_df.b6)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
print(pd.concat([BallOne, BallTwo, BallThree, BallFour, BallFive, BallSix], keys = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6'], axis=1),("\n"))
df.to_csv('Filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you Serialize `df` instead you didn't write out you `pd.concat`
operation, you better do

```
df = pd.concat([BallOne, BallTwo, BallThree, BallFour, BallFive, BallSix], keys = ['B1','B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6'],axis=1)
```

And this should get better